# Remote variables (network usage, processor load, open process, and so) via PHP

Tags: php, html, remote-access

i run a php server, i want to develop a php script that when called by an user it echo network usage, processor load, open process, and so from the server. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [exec function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) in which you can run sys commands, and it returns the output as a string(in which you can parse).

An example:

```
<?php
$output = array();

exec("ps" , $output);

var_dump($output);

?>
```

Output:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(28) "  PID TTY           TIME CMD"
  [1]=>
  string(30) "12986 ttys000    0:00.24 -bash"
  [2]=>
  string(28) "13033 ttys000    0:01.06 irb"
  [3]=>
  string(28) "13054 ttys000    0:01.38 irb"
  [4]=>
  string(40) "14975 ttys000    0:00.06 php -f test.php"
  [5]=>
  string(30) "14010 ttys005    0:00.11 -bash"
  [6]=>
  string(31) "14367 ttys005    0:00.07 python"
}
```

Comment: Any example will be nice, Thanks!

Comment: A lot this sort of data can be read from the `/proc/` filesystem as well

Comment: Thanks now i get it, but i cant find any DOS command who tells me the load on the procesor or the opened process, any idea? Thanks again!

Comment: I'd read this article http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1575 on finding CPU usage, etc via command line.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things I knocked out over the weekend that read from the `/proc/` filesystem -- this may be lighter weight than forking via `exec()`, although it may also be less portable.

```
function getMem() {
    $mem = '';
    if($r = @file_get_contents('/proc/meminfo')) {
        $dat = array();
        foreach(explode("\n", $r) as $line) {
            if(preg_match('/^([^:]+):[ ]+([0-9]+.*)$/', $line, $matches))
                $dat[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
        $free = (int)((@$dat['MemFree'] + @$dat['Cached']) / 1024);
        $mem = $free . 'MB / ' . (int)(@$dat['MemTotal'] / 1024) . 'MB';
    }
    return $mem;
}

function getLoad() {
    $load = null;
    if($r = @file_get_contents('/proc/loadavg')) {
        $l = explode(' ', $r);
        $load = implode(' ', array($l[0], $l[1], $l[2]));
    }
    return $load;
}
```